# How to run a command with arguments in Laravel Vapor

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

I Just started testing Laravel Vapor, everything working well except I'm using filament package which it needs to run a command to create admin user, the command is working locally on my computer and I have a user now, but in production when I execute the command (**./vendor/bin/vapor command production**) and then the command that creates the user (**php artisan make:filament-user**). vapor not giving any input to enter my name and my email address. So is there anyway to give arguments for commands in vapor? or is there anyway to give the these arguments with the command? thank you

Comment: You can pass the arguments in the string like the example in the docs: vapor command production --command="php artisan make:filament-user username user@example.com".  I think you wrote your command to use prompts though.

Answer (score 1):

simple, just use your command by command line in the console or inside vapor page, menu commands in your project, example:

php artisan <command_name> '<arguments_parameters>'

my job command with argument:
php artisan metric:consolidate '2022-01-29 00:00' (job name with date start argument).